# Specify rules for 2D cellular automaton?

Tags: cellular-automata

If I want my rule to affect cells in this way:

- dead $\to$ dead $\iff$ Cell has $n$ living neighbours, $n\in A$
- dead $\to$ alive$\iff$ Cell has $n$ living neighbours, $n\in B$
- alive $\to$ dead $\iff$ Cell has $n$ living neighbours, $n\in C$
- alive $\to$ alive $\iff$ Cell has $n$ living neighbours, $n\in D$

(where neighborhood of a cell consists of all closest surrounding cells)

Then, how do I specify my `rule`?

```
ArrayPlot[Last[CellularAutomaton[rule, board, step]]]
```

For example, if $A=C=\{0,2,4,6,8\}, B=D=\{1,3,5,7\}$, and

```
board = Table[If[i == j == 20, 1, 0], {i, 1, 41}, {j, 1, 41}]
```

and `step` goes from $0$ to $15$, then we should have this replicator pattern:

[image]

*Which was taken from* [Terrific Toothpick Patterns - at 14:51](https://youtu.be/_UtCli1SgjI?t=891)

So how to convert given $A,B,C,D$ to a `rule` that gives, for example the pattern above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example where $A = C$ and $B = D$ can be achieved using `GrowthSurvivalCases` option of `CellularAutomata` (as of Mathematica 11.1, I believe):

```
init = CenterArray[{30, 30}];

res = CellularAutomaton[<|
    "Dimension" -> 2,
    "GrowthSurvivalCases" -> {
      {1, 3, 5, 7},
      {1, 3, 5, 7}
      }|>, init, 15];

Partition[ArrayPlot /@ res, 3] // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

The following code worked for me:

```
a = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
b = {1, 3, 5, 7};
c = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
d = {1, 3, 5, 7};
Manipulate[
 Row[{cell3 = CellularAutomaton[{
      Which[
        MemberQ[a, 
          Mod[Total[# - #[[2, 2]], \[Infinity]], 2]] \[And] #[[2, 
       2]] == 0, 0,
    MemberQ[b, 
      Mod[Total[# - #[[2, 2]], \[Infinity]], 2]] \[And] #[[2, 
       2]] == 0, 1,
    MemberQ[c, 
      Mod[Total[# - #[[2, 2]], \[Infinity]], 2]] \[And] #[[2, 
       2]] == 1, 0,
    MemberQ[d, 
      Mod[Total[# - #[[2, 2]], \[Infinity]], 2]] \[And] #[[2, 
       2]] == 1, 1
    ] &,
  {}, {1, 1}}, {{{1}}, 0}, {{{i}}}],
ArrayPlot[cell3, ImageSize -> 300, Mesh -> True, 
MeshStyle -> Red]}],
{i, 0, 10, 1}]
```

[image: Cellular automata with Manipulate function.]

It's a bit clumsy as this is my first time working with cellular automata but I think it works. I may not be understanding the math behind the automata correctly, but I'm not sure if the "GrowthSurvivalCases" option will get you exactly what you want if we have $A \neq C$ and $B \neq D$.

The documentation states:

> With "GrowthSurvivalCases"->{{Subscript[g,
>   1],[Ellipsis]},{Subscript[s, 1],[Ellipsis]}}, a cell goes from value
>   0 to value 1 if it has Subscript[g, i] neighbors that are 1, maintains
>   value 1 if it has Subscript[s, i] neighbors that are 1, and otherwise
>   gets value 0.

In this case, the $g_i$ correspond to $B$ and the $s_i$ correspond to $D$, but regardless of whether a cell was previously dead or alive, it will be switched to dead if the number is not listed in $B$ or $D$, which is why I used the `Which` to test all 4 cases instead.